# Does order of schema matter in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, schema, mean-stack

Im about to make a huge schema for a form that I have just built... that being said does my schema order have to mimic the form order, or can it just have all the inputs in any order I put them in ?
Example below.
can it be like this?

```
// link to mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the article schema
var mapSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
created: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
},
dd1: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
dd2: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
com1: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
com2: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
}
});

// make it public
module.exports = mongoose.model('Map', mapSchema);
```

Or does it have to be like this?

```
// link to mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the article schema
var mapSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 created: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now
},
dd1: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
com1: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
 dd2: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
com2: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
}
});

// make it public
module.exports = mongoose.model('Map', mapSchema);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does my schema order have to mimic the form order, or can it just have all the inputs in any order I put them in?

`mongoose.Schema` accepts a JavaScript object as its parameter. So your question boils down to:

**Are JavaScript objects aware of the order their keys were defined in?**

The answer to that is: No, key order is not maintained in JavaScript objects. The JS spec explicitly states that objects are unordered key/value collections. ([compare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/18771))

Therefore it follows that `mongoose.Schema` could not rely on key order even if it tied to, which means you are free to order the keys in any way you like.

---

We can also tackle the question from the other end:

**Is it likely that a front-end change like form field order forces me to rewrite my database backend code?**

And the answer to that is: No, that is pretty darn unlikely. We can dismiss that thought without even looking into any kind of spec, because it would not make any kind of sense.